# GNATprove: "postcondition might fail" in simple function

Tags: ada, formal-verification, spark-ada, spark-formal-verification

I want to write a simple function that finds the biggest number in given Integer array. Here is specification:

```
package Maximum with SPARK_Mode is

   type Vector is array(Integer range <>) of Integer;

   function Maximum (A : in Vector) return Integer
     with
       SPARK_Mode,
       Pre => A'Length > 0,
         Post =>
         (for all i in A'Range => A(i) <= Maximum'Result)
         and then
           (for some i in A'Range => A(i) = Maximum'Result);

end Maximum;
```

And here is function's body:

```
package body Maximum with SPARK_Mode is

   function Maximum (A : in Vector) return Integer
   is
   Max : Integer := A (A'First);
   begin
      if (A'Length = 1) then
         return Max;
      end if;

      for I in A'First + 1 .. A'Last loop
         pragma Loop_Invariant
           (for all Index in A'First .. I - 1 => Max >= A(Index));

         if A (I) > Max then
            Max := A (I);
         end if;
      end loop;

      return Max;
   end Maximum;

end Maximum;
```

And when I try to prove this function with SPARK, it says that postcondition might fail. I'm trying to understand this for like 5 hours now and I have no idea why it says so. It's really annoying, this function MUST work. Do you have any idea why SPARK behaves so strange? What is a data example for this function to not fullfil its postcondition? It always returns a value taken directly from given array and it is always maximal.

Comment: Notice that gnatprove says "might".  It doesn't mean that it has a counter-example.  It only means that it can't prove that the postcondition is fulfilled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is to make a loop invariant, which is weaker than the postcondition:

Specification:

```ada
package Maximum
  with SPARK_Mode
is

   type Vector is array (Integer range <>) of Integer;

   function Maximum (A : in Vector) return Integer
     with
       Pre  => A'Length > 0,
       Post => (for all i in A'Range => A(i) <= Maximum'Result)
               and
               (for some i in A'Range => A(i) = Maximum'Result);

end Maximum;
```

Implementation:

```ada
package body Maximum with SPARK_Mode is

   function Maximum (A : in Vector) return Integer
   is
   Max : Integer := A (A'First);
   begin
      if (A'Length = 1) then
         return Max;
      end if;

      for K in A'First + 1 .. A'Last loop
         pragma Loop_Invariant
           ((for all  I in A'First .. K - 1 => A (I) <= Max)
            and
            (for some I in A'First .. K - 1 => A (I) = Max));

         if A (K) > Max then
            Max := A (K);
         end if;
      end loop;

      return Max;
   end Maximum;

end Maximum;
```

Project file:

```ada
project Maximum is
   for Main use ("maximum");
end Maximum;
```

Comment: Yes, yes, thank you! I figured it out a few hours after I asked this question anyway but I'm glad to see someone actually giving a good answer (I had like 5 views 3 hours after posting this).
These SPARK's messages are very misleading by the way.

Comment: I typically only check out questions, when I get my daily summary of new questions, so getting a response from me before 24 hours have passed is fast.